# next function not working on the first time

Tags: javascript, html, function

Here is the [CODE](http://studio.html5rocks.com/#Deck) where i am facing problem.

Let me explain the problem briefly. 
The html code contains many slides such that the slides will move front and back when the arrow keys are pressed and on mouse scroll too.

The issue is that the arrow keys when pressed for the first time the next function inside it is not working.

But when I use scroll the next function start executing and after that when I click the left arrow it works.

But it is not working on the first time. Whats the issue.? How can I solve it?

here is the next function:

```
next: function() {
            if (!this._slides[this.current-1].buildNext()) {
              this.current = Math.min(this.current + 1, this._slides.length);
              this._update();
            }
```

Here is the code where it is called:

```
handleWheel: function(e) {
            var delta = 0;
            if (e.wheelDelta) {
              delta = e.wheelDelta/120;
              if (isOpera) {
                delta = -delta;
              }
            } else if (e.detail) {
              delta = -e.detail/3;
            }

            if (delta > 0 ) {
              this.prev();
              return;
            }
            if (delta < 0 ) {
              this.next();
              return;
            }
          },
          handleKeys: function(e) {
            if (/^(input|textarea)$/i.test(e.target.nodeName) ||
                e.target.isContentEditable) {
              return;
            }
            switch (e.keyCode) {
              //case 37: // left arrow
                //this.prev(); break;
              case 39: // right arrow
              case 32: // space
                this.next(); break;
              case 50: // 2
                this.showNotes(); break;
              case 51: // 3
                this.switch3D(); break;
            }
          }
```

Comment: why this much of down votes when he has already provided the live sample in the question itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the code where if condition is the problem

```
   next: function() {
                if (!this._slides[this.current-1].buildNext()) {
                  this.current = Math.min(this.current + 1, this._slides.length);
                  this._update();
                }
}
```

This is the edited code which works fine

```
next: function() {

              this.current = Math.min(this.current + 1, this._slides.length);
              this._update();
            }
```